# How can get Month Name and year from the existing data

Tags: excel, vba

This the data I have.

I just want its month name and year.

For example `201804`: `Apr 2018`

[image]

Comment: Please add your image to your post. Where do you want month name and year returned and how? Do you want a formula or do you want VBA? Formula: `=Text(A1,"mmm yyyy")`, or just change the `Format Type`. VBA: `Format(myString,"mmm yyyy")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this UDF

```
Sub Test()
    Debug.Print FormatDate("201804")
End Sub

Function FormatDate(sInput As String)
    sInput = "1/" & Right(sInput, 2) & "/" & Left(sInput, 4)
    FormatDate = Format(CDate(sInput), "mmm yyyy")
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Sub test()
    Dim vDB
    Dim i As Long
    Dim s As String, y As String, m As String

    vDB = Range("a1", Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

    For i = 2 To UBound(vDB, 1)
        s = vDB(i, 1)
        y = Left(s, 4)
        m = Right(s, 2)
        vDB(i, 1) = Format(DateSerial(y, m, 1), "mmm yyyy")
    Next i
    With Range("b1").Resize(UBound(vDB, 1), 1)
        .NumberFormatLocal = "@"
        .Value = vDB
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the worksheet formula, converting the date in A1. Copy the formula down as required.

`=DATE(LEFT(A1,4),RIGHT(A1,2),1)`

The result is a proper date set for the first day of the month, in this case April 1, 2018. The format in which this result is displayed depends entirely upon your system settings. However, you can over-ride the system by setting a custom date format in Format > Cells > Numbers > Custom*. Set *Type* as `mmm yyyy` to display *Apr 2018* in the cell.